# How can I use a FOREACH loop inside of a WHILE loop to create several columns

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, while-loop, multiple-columns

**PROBLEM**

I am pulling data from my database...using a WHILE loop & I want the returned data to be coupled into "scalable in size" groups.

I thought that by using a FOREACH LOOP inside of the while loop, I could accomplish this, apparently I thought wrong..ARRG!

**LINK**

View problem here: http://sis-cr.com/NEWSTORE/store.php?cur_str=cel

**CODE**

```
$queryCatz = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT DISTINCT idBrand FROM Products ");
while($list_of_xtras = mysqli_fetch_array($queryCatz)) {     

    $cur = 0;
    $rowNum = 1;
    foreach($list_of_xtras as $key => $value){

        if($cur == 0){
            echo '<ul style="border:2px solid purple;" class="theROW' . $rowNum . '">';
        }

        echo '    <li style="list-style:none;">' . $value. '</li>';

        if($cur == 2)
        {
            echo '</ul>';
            $cur = 0;
            $rowNum++;
        }
        else
        {
            $cur++;
        }
    }


}
```

**After 3 hours** of trying to fix this, and at the risk of exposing my very obvious lack on understanding, ***I humbly*** bow before the collective minds of SO....and shout...HELP, I've coded and can't get up!

Comment: I think you want to increment `$rowNum` outside of your `foreach()`. Also could you give us an example result or what you would expect to have?

Comment: Oh dear I see what happened, I didn't look at your link.

Comment: Are you trying to have rows of X amount of entries show?

Comment: You are only selecting ONE COLUMN so `$cur` will never be equal to 2. So you never close the unordered list.

Comment: I would like to have nested in a UL 10 results afterwhich another 10 results inside of another UL....and so on

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you give an example...I don't see how I only selected one column

Comment: Like this `SELECT DISTINCT idBrand`... only one field returned in each result row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be off track. I think you want:

```
$queryCatz = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT DISTINCT idBrand FROM Products ");
while($list_of_xtras = mysqli_fetch_array($queryCatz)) {     
  $rowNum = 1;
  echo '<ul style="border:2px solid purple;" class="theROW' . $rowNum . '">\r\n';
  for($curr=0; $curr<2; $curr++){
    echo '\t<li style="list-style:none;">' . $list_of_xtras[$curr] . '</li>\r\n';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
  $rowNum++;
}
```

Seems like you're just looking for 2 results, so I don't know if FOREACH is best here. Maybe just a FOR loop.

Edit, after I saw your comment. Sounds like you want to wrap 10 results in a UL. To do that it would be something like:

```
$rowNum = 1;
echo '<ul style="border:2px solid purple;" class="theROW' . $rowNum . '">\r\n';
$queryCatz = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT DISTINCT idBrand FROM Products ");
while($list_of_xtras = mysqli_fetch_array($queryCatz)) {     
  if($rowNum % 10 == 0){
    echo '</ul><ul style="border:2px solid purple;" class="theROW' . $rowNum . '">\r\n';
  }
  echo '\t<li style="list-style:none;">' . $list_of_xtras[0] . '</li>\r\n';
  $rowNum++;
}
echo "</ul>\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks @twisty! Worked like a charm...I was trying to get something that I could re-use..so thank you very much!